# Playwright JS: How to take screenshot for failed test cases in jest test

Tags: jestjs, screenshot, playwright

There is a way to take screenshots whenever test cases fail in Playwright Test Runner using a config file. I am using Jest as a test runner for Playwright JS tests - is there a way to achieve the same thing using Jest?

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this to Your setup file:

```
global.test = async (name, func) => {
return await it(name, async () => {
  try {
    await func();
  } catch (e) {
    const date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    const dateOfMonth = date.getUTCDate();
    const hour = date.getUTCHours();
    const minute = date.getUTCMinutes();
    const sec = date.getUTCSeconds();
    const dateString = `${year}-${month}-${dateOfMonth}-${hour}-${minute}-${sec}`;

    const errorScreenshotPath = `screenshots/${browserName}-${dateString}-${name.replace(
      / /g,
      "_"
    )}.png`;
      await page.screenshot({
        path: errorScreenshotPath,
      });

    throw e;
  }
});};
```

It will not support other test globals, but it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works for me here:
https://github.com/playwright-community/jest-playwright#using-with-different-jest-environments
Just override default PlaywrightEnvironment with a custom CustomEnvironment.js:

```
const PlaywrightEnvironment = require('jest-playwright-preset/lib/PlaywrightEnvironment')
  .default

class CustomEnvironment extends PlaywrightEnvironment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup()
    // Your setup
  }

  async teardown() {
    // Your teardown
    await super.teardown()
  }

  async handleTestEvent(event) {
    await super.handleTestEvent(event);
    if (event.name === 'test_done' && event.test.errors.length > 0) {
      const parentName = event.test.parent.name.replace(/\W/g, '-')
      const specName = event.test.name.replace(/\W/g, '-')

      await this.global.page.screenshot({
        path: `screenshots/${parentName}_${specName}.png`,
      })
    }
  }
}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment
```

Update jest.config.json:

```
testEnvironment: "./CustomEnvironment.js"
```